Can't login to my CiviCRM Spark instance or get a password reset
I just signed up to CiviCRM Spark, at the $50/month level, but although I've received a receipt, I didn't receive login instruction.  Also, password reset's don't appear to work, even though I'm definitely using the email shown in the receipt.
Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated...

Please get in touch with the support team at spark@civicrm.org. they might be able to help you.

Thanks.  I did just that!
